# iOS: How to expire a local notification with a region trigger?

Tags: ios, swift, location, uilocalnotification, geofencing

I have a local geofence notification, set up with the following code:

```
func startMonitoring(annotation:MKAnnotation) {

    let region = CLCircularRegion(center: annotation.coordinate, radius: 10.0, identifier: "randomID")
    region.notifyOnExit = false

    let notification = UILocalNotification()
    notification.region = region
    notification.alertBody = "You got it!"
    notification.category = self.notificationCategory
    notification.soundName = "my_sound.wav"
    notification.userInfo = ["ID": "randomID"]

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification)
}
```

This works great, but the user has to get to the area within a certain time limit for the action of the notification to be available. How can I make the notification NOT fire if the time limit has passed?

I currently only have "WhenInUse" authorization for the user's location and would prefer to keep it that way.

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off monitoring the CLCircularRegion manually using CLLocationManager, and when your app is notified that the user has entered the region, check whether it's in the time limit and post your UILocalNotification manually.

See the section `Using Regions to Monitor Boundary Crossings` here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html

Comment: Does that not mean I need to request Always-authorization for the user's location? I'll do that if I absolutely must, but would prefer not to.

Comment: Yes but that is the case for UILocalNotifications with a Region anyway: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Reference/UILocalNotification_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILocalNotification/region

Comment: No, it's not. The documentation is slightly unclear, but I've got them working now with only WhenInUse authorization for the user's location.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup background fetch with `setminimumbackgroundfetchinterval` , and cancel the scheduled notification if it's going to expire.

It's not 100% reliable because you cannot control exact time, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12416131)

Comment: @David'mArm'Ansermot I actually find this suggestion very useful, and don't see how it doesn't answer my question. If there is no actual way of doing what I want, an alternative solution is very welcome (to me at least).